# Numpy not found in python and found in ipython

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

I installed numpy using pip. when I run ipython, numpy is imported successfully but when I run python and import numpy I get

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I tried to set `$PYTHONPATH` to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
but then I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUnicodeEscapeString
```

I am using 
python 2.7.6
and Ipython 4.1.1

Comment: Do you have more than one Python installed? Which Python version is displayed when you run ipython?

Comment: They are the same python versions. 2.7.6

Comment: Then `pip`'s version is not correct. Please try `pip2`.

Comment: I used pip2 and got
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages